# Python 3: Crash with free(): corrupted unsorted chunks while reading file

Tags: python, python-3.x, crash

I found the following strange behavior with Python 3:

```
file = open(path, mode='rb').read()
file_ori = open(self.filePath, mode='rb').read()

m = hashlib.md5()
md5 = m.update(file)
md5 = m.hexdigest()

file = '0x'.encode('ascii') + binascii.hexlify(file)
file_ori = '0x'.encode('ascii') + binascii.hexlify(file_ori)
```

In this scenario my application will crash sooner or later with *free(): corrupted unsorted chunks*.

If I change to code to:

```
file = open(path, mode='rb')
file_ori = open(self.filePath, mode='rb')

filecont = file.read()
file_oricont = file_ori.read()

m = hashlib.md5()
md5 = m.update(filecont)
md5 = m.hexdigest()

fileb = '0x'.encode('ascii') + binascii.hexlify(filecont)
fileb_ori = '0x'.encode('ascii') + binascii.hexlify(file_oricont)
```

The application is running without problems.

I read the documentation multiple times but can't find any reason for this behavior. Did someone may know more about this? It seems to me there is a bug with Python and the garbage collection?

I tested with python3.4 and python3.5.

Thanks
Manuel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**first exemple** : Tested in python 2.7 worked and tell me in wich line the   error  occurs

**second exemple** : You have to know when you call f.read() the cursor in the file gets to the end of the file so another f.read() will output nothing ie '' so the two exemples are differents

Comment: Absolutely right with the read. This was my mistake. I will adjust the sample.